# Is there a way to set up a filter where only the information entered can be shared to a user in Tableau?

Tags: filtering, sharing, tableau-api

I have a Tableau workbook I want to share to the team.  I have wildcard filters set to change across all pages when an individual enters their name.  However, I do not want the individuals to see their peer's info.

Looking for a way to sort of have something prompt the user to enter a password (something similar) to have the filter automatically change to their name???  that way when they receive the workbook, they can only see their information.. All help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is called row level security. By providing the specific username per attribute it will do this for you. Check this out: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/row-level-security-and-user-filters

Comment: P.S. I hope you mean Carolina Panthers. My fav team as well

Comment: And yes, HUGE fan also!  You are a blessing.  Thank you!